# How to call a jsonp using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this api http://api.program-o.com/v2/chatbot/?bot_id=6&say=what%20is%20your%20name&convo_id=exampleusage_1231232&format=xml which I call using the browser then I am getting proper response. But when I call using jquery ajax then I am getting the error

```
*Refused to execute script from 'http://api.program-o.com/v2/chatbot/?bot_id=6&say=what%20is%20your%20name&c…ormat=xml&callback=?%20&callback=jQuery172005527849208121283_1460880216789' because its MIME type ('text/xml') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.*
```

code is as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>JQuery (cross-domain) JSONP Twitter example</title>
        <script type="text/javascript"src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
    url: "http://api.program-o.com/v2/chatbot/?bot_id=6&say=what%20is%20your%20name&convo_id=exampleusage_1231232&format=xml&callback=? ",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    cache: true,
    success: function (data, status, error) {
      console.log('success', data);
    },
    error: function (data, status, error) {
      console.log('error', data, status, error);
    }
});
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="gists"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can anybody please tell me why I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your response is a XML file. You should change the `format` query to `json`.

Here is the response in JSON:

```
{"convo_id":"exampleusage_1231232","usersay":"WHAT IS YOUR NAME","botsay":"My name is Program-O."}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://api.program-o.com/v2/chatbot/?bot_id=6&say=what%20is%20your%20name&convo_id=exampleusage_1231232&format=xml&callback=? ",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'jsonp',
```

You're requesting for `XML`

`http://api.program-o.com/v2/chatbot/?bot_id=6&say=what%20is%20your%20name&convo_id=exampleusage_1231232&format=xml`

If you replace `XML` with `JSON` it should work.

`http://api.program-o.com/v2/chatbot/?bot_id=6&say=what%20is%20your%20name&
convo_id=exampleusage_1231232&format=json`

Comment: yes, but it seems `api.program-o.com` do not support json-p

Comment: @RubenYeghikyan I have already tried the way you suggested but I am getting the same error

Comment: @SpringLearner yeah, the problem is API as it do not support jsonp or crossDomain requests. I think you need to contact with API developer.

Comment: I have tried with other BOT api too,still the same. Do you know any bot api where jsonP and cross domain works

Answer (score 0):

When u try to make a direct call to 
`http://api.program-o.com/v2/chatbot/?bot_id=6&say=what%20is%20your%20name&convo_id=exampleusage_1231232&format=json` in your browser, you will notice the return headers are `Content-Type:text/plain; charset=utf-8` and `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff`. It tells the Chrome to have a strict MIME type check. Can you try change the server output Content-Type to `application/javascript` or remove the `X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff`?

Comment: I dont have any control in sever, so I can not change the server thing. Without changing the server thing,isnt any possible to show the output in webpage using ajax?